# how to make my program not crash when entering a character besides a number

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a bank program. I have finished most of my code but I am stuck on one thing. Every time I try to deposit or withdraw and enter a character different from a number, my program crashes. I just wanted to know how I could use a try and except statement to make this not crash. My code is attached below.

```
def printmenu():
    print("======================")
    print("Welcome to Dons Bank")
    print("What can I do for you?")
    print("1 - Withdraw Funds")
    print("2 - Deposit Funds")
    print("3 - Show Balance")
    print("4 - Quit")

    def main():
        myBalance = 1000
        userChoice = 0
        invalidcharac = True
        printmenu()
        while invalidcharac:
            try: 
                userChoice = int(input("Please choose one of the above options: "))
                invalidcharac = False
            except ValueError:
                print("Invalid option.  Please choose an option by entering 1, 2, 3, or 4.")
        while userChoice != 4:
            if userChoice == 1:
                amount = int(input("Amount to withdraw: "))
                while myBalance - amount < 0:
                    print("Sorry: you don't have that much money in your account.")
                    amount = int(input("Amount to withdraw: "))
                myBalance = myBalance - amount
                print("New balance: ", myBalance)
            elif userChoice == 2:
                amount = int(input("Amount to deposit: "))
                myBalance = myBalance + amount
                print("New balance: ", myBalance)
            elif userChoice == 3:
                print("Balance: ", myBalance)
            elif userChoice == 4:
                continue
            else:
                print("Invalid option. Please choose an option by entering 1, 2, 3, or 4.")
        print("Thank you. Goodbye!")

    main()
```

Comment: Just do it the same way you did for the `Please choose one of the above options` input. Could move it to a new function to reduce redundancy.

Comment: would i start the try statement under if userChoice == 1: ?

Answer (score 0):

As always, you can tweak the messages

```
def printmenu():
    print("=" * 20)
    print("Welcome to Dons Bank")
    print("What can I do for you?")
    print("1 - Withdraw Funds")
    print("2 - Deposit Funds")
    print("3 - Show Balance")
    print("4 - Quit")
    print("=" * 20)

def main():
    myBalance = 1000
    userChoice = 0
#    invalidcharac = True
    printmenu()

    while True:
        try: 
            userChoice = int(input("Please choose one of the above options: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid option.  Please choose an option by entering 1, 2, 3, or 4.")
            continue

        if userChoice == 1:
            try:

                amount = int(input("Amount to withdraw: "))
                while myBalance - amount < 0:
                    print("Sorry: you don't have that much money in your account.")
                    amount = int(input("Amount to withdraw: "))
                myBalance = myBalance - amount
                print("New balance: ", myBalance)
            except:
                print("Invalid option. Reset to menu.")
                continue

        elif userChoice == 2:
            try:
                amount = int(input("Amount to deposit: "))
                myBalance = myBalance + amount
                print("New balance: ", myBalance)
            except:
                print("Invalid option. Reset to menu.")
                continue

        elif userChoice == 3:
            print("Your balance is: ", myBalance)
        elif userChoice == 4:
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid option. Please choose an option by entering 1, 2, 3, or 4.")
    print("Thank you. Goodbye!")

main()
```